# Symmetric equation with point and line

Tags: linear-algebra

Find the symmetric equation for a plane which passes through point (1,2,3) and perpendicular to line x-3=y-4=z-1.

I eventually got x+y+z=6 (someone please confirm this), but I do not know how to convert from standard form to the symmetric equation. How should i do this?

Comment: Give an example of a “symmetric equation” for a plane. I’ve only heard of this for lines.

Comment: $\frac{x-x_0}{a}=\frac{y-y_0}{b}=\frac{z-z_0}{c}$

Comment: That’s the equation of a line, not a plane. Are you sure that you’ve read the problem statement correctly?